# maximum number of recursive SQL levels

Tags: oracle, triggers

```
    java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00036: maximum number of recursive SQL levels (50) exceeded ORA-06512: at "EPOLICIA.EMER_COMPLAINT_VALIDATE", 
line 5 ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'EPOLICIA.EMER_COMPLAINT_VALIDATE' ORA-06512: at "EPOLICIA.EMER_COMPLAINT_VALIDATE", 
line 5 ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'EPOLICIA.EMER_COMPLAINT_VALIDATE' ORA-06512: at "EPOLICIA.EMER_COMPLAINT_VALIDATE", 
line 5 ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'EPOLICIA.EMER_COMPLAINT_VALIDATE' ORA-06512: at "EPOLICIA.EMER_COMPLAINT_VALIDATE", 
line 5 ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'EPOLICIA.EMER_COMPLAINT_VALIDATE' ORA-06512: at "EPOLICIA.EMER_COMPLAINT_VALIDATE", 
line 5 ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'EPOLICIA.EMER_COMPLAINT_VALIDATE' ORA-06512: at "EPOLICIA.EMER_COMPLAINT_VALIDATE", 
line 5 ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'EPOLICIA.EMER_COMPLAINT_VALIDATE' ORA-06512: at "EPOLICIA.EMER_COMPLAINT_VALIDATE", 
line 5 ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'EPOLICIA.EMER_COMPLAINT_VALIDATE' ORA-06512: at "EPOLICIA.EMER_COMPLAINT_VALIDATE", 
line 5 ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'EPOLICIA.EMER_COMPLAINT_VALIDATE' ORA-06512: at "EPOLICIA.EMER_COMPLAINT_VALIDATE", 
line 5 ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'EPOLICIA.EMER_COMPLAINT_VALIDATE' ORA-06512: at "EPOLICIA.EMER_COMPLAINT_VALIDATE", 
line 5 ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'EPOLICIA.EMER_COMPLAINT_VALIDATE' ORA-06512: at "EPOLICIA.EMER_COMPLAINT_VALIDATE", 
line 5 ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'EPOLICIA.EMER_COMPLAINT_VALIDATE' ORA-06512: at "EPOLICIA.EMER_COMPLAINT_VALIDATE", 
line 5 ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'EPOLICIA.EMER_COMPLAINT_VALIDATE' ORA-06512: at "EPOLICIA.EMER_COMPLAINT_VALIDATE", 
line 5 ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'EPOLICIA.EMER_COMPLAINT_VALIDATE' ORA-06512: at "EPOLICIA.EMER_COMPLAINT_VALIDATE", 
line 5 ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'EPOLICIA.EMER_COMPLAINT_VALIDATE' ORA-06512: at "EPOLICIA.EMER_COMPLAINT_VALIDATE", 
line 5 ORA-04
```

I've created one trigger, by which i will restrict the user to **accept only one complaint from a particular ip address in a single day**.

**EMER_COMPLAINT_VALIDATE**

```
create or replace trigger emer_complaint_validate before insert on emer_complaint for each row
begin
if(((:new.date_time) = (:old.date_time)) AND ((:new.ip_add) = (:old.ip_add))) then
RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001, 'Only one complaint accepted !!'); 
ELSE
insert into emer_complaint values(:new.case_id,:new.complaint,:new.land_mark,:new.station_id,:new.date_time,:new.ip_add,:new.status);
end if;
end;
/
```

structure of table, on which trigger has applied
[image: EMER_COMPLAINT]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is a constraint, not a trigger. In 11g:

```
ALTER TABLE emer_complaint 
   ADD (date_complaint DATE GENERATED ALWAYS AS (trunc(date_time)));

ALTER TABLE emer_complaint 
   ADD CONSTRAINT "one complaint per day" UNIQUE (ip_add, date_complaint);
```

In 10g and before:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "one complaint per day" 
   ON emer_complaint (ip_add, trunc(date_time));
```

[Don't use triggers for (cross-row) integrity](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:53473305799476).

Comment: I appreciate your suggestion. So, it will check on date basis or timestamp. Because, every moment is a unique one. So, i need comparison on date basis only. So, it will fulfill my requirement..??

Comment: I used `trunc(date_time)` in both cases. This will select the date without the time component (so one complaint per ip **per day**).

Comment: +1  This is the one and only correct approach.  When will people learn that triggers are no good for enforcing relational integrity?

Comment: I tried up voting multiple times. Luckily I stopped after an odd number of clicks on the up triangle. As APC says, "the one and only correct approach" and worth more rep than I can give.